# First selected item value from checkbox collection

Tags: jquery, css

My html code is as below.

```
 <table id="rooms">
            <tbody>
                <% 
                    var rooms = Model.AvailableRooms.ToList();
                %>
                <tr>
                    <% 
                        foreach (var r in rooms)
                        {         
                    %><td style="text-align: center">
                        <input type="checkbox"
                            value="<%: r.Id %>-<%: r.Name %>-<%: Model.Provider.Key %>" />
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: center">
                        <%: r.Name %> 
                    </td>
                    <% 
                        } 
                    %>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

From that I need to get the first selected item's value.How could I do that ?

Comment: What means "first selected item"?

Comment: Please post the rendered HTML, not whatever language that is.

Comment: @Johnツ I am having check box collection.But I need only one selected item's value.Even though others are selected i don't need.I need only one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jQuery selectors to get it:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']:checked").first().val()
```

or

```
$("input[type='checkbox']:checked:first").val()
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Nd66s/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').first()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#rooms input:checked:first').val()
```